# Xcode begins with breakpoint "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2"

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time when I run Xcode it begins with the breakpoint in main.m at

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

There is no breakpoint assigned there.

Comment: Actually I want to debug my code, but whenever the simulation begins the code stops in this point, even without breakpoints.

Comment: The project works fine, my colleagues don´t have this problem. and I already uninstalled and reinstalled the whole environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also edit Exceptions breakpoint and choose only Objective-C exception. In my case it helped me.

[image: Screenshot of Breakpoint navigator]

Answer (score 6):

maybe you can try like this:

Make sure you that all fonts that you specify in your Info.plist under Fonts provided by this application are actually in your application bundle.

The font will lead to C++ breakPoint 1.2

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have a global Exceptions breakpoint. For some reason, an exception is being thrown. But not every exception is fatal; this one is being caught internally by Cocoa. So, you have two choices:

- Hit the Exceptions breakpoint and resume.
- Temporarily turn off the Exceptions breakpoint (in the Breakpoints navigator).

It is a little infuriating that this happens, but that's how it is. There are a lot of situations where Cocoa throws *and catches* an exception internally. (For example, AVFoundation does this a lot.) This would normally go unnoticed, but when you have a global Exceptions breakpoint enabled, it causes a pause whenever this occurs.

Comment: I'm not crashing, I'm sure.. as i said, Xcode shows: “Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2” message and I can continue/step over this breakpoint, and continuing the running normally.

Comment: I just had the same thing happen, so I'm sure now that it's an Exceptions breakpoint. You can see this in the Breakpoints navigator.

Comment: I too find it very infuriating that this is happening. I couldn't catch a bug one time with my own breakpoints, I then used the all exceptions breakpoint to catch this, now I've spent some time figuring this exact thing out. Why in gods name is it throwing exceptions when one cannot catch these.

Answer (score 3):

You may have accidentally set a breakpoint without noticing. You have to disable all of your app breakpoints.

- You can disable all your breakpoint by click,
  -> Debug menu -> deactivate breakpoints
- you can delete specific breakpoint by, Click and drag the blue tick representing the breakpoint outside of the gutter.